# Deserialization version conflicts

Tags: java, deserialization

My question is what is a good way to implement upgrading outdated objects?

For example say you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo() implements Serializable {
    int a;
    String b;
}
```

and then you serialize this object. Then later on you add more functionality to your class by say adding:

```
...
int c;
...
```

You still want to retain the information that is in the serialized object but I know that if you try to deserialize it there will be conflicts. So is there a way (maybe by checking serialVersionUID) to set a value for `int c` knowing that it won't exist?

Thanks

Comment: did you mean you want to add an `int c` or something later? Because `b` is already a `String`.

Comment: Haha yes I did, silly me. It's late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a private method:

```
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) {
      // compare serialVersionUID and determine which fields to expect
      // read the expected fields for that version
      // initialize the new fields.
    }
```

For more information, read the [serialization specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/version.html#6678)

Comment: I looked at what you linked to and that's very helpful. It says that you can implement the readObject function like you said. But Java still complains about the serialVersionUID being different. How exactly do I implement this function?

Comment: I put this function in my class and put in

Foo obj = (Foo) ois.readObject();
ObjectStreamClass.lookup(obj.getClass()).getSerialVersionUID()

according to a site i found but it's still not letting it work because of the different serialVersionUID's. What it's looking like I can do is have a different variable to monitor versions and check that to see what to do because then it won't error. Please correct me if I am wrong because I want to do this the correct way and I want to learn.

Comment: You're probably right - please code and confirm.  Just keep track of your version might be simpler - like 1 or 2, or even the version can be the number of fields, so your version difference will tell you how many field values you need to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very smart idea about using number of fields for version number. So I tried doing this but I just can't seem to figure out what to put in the function. I can't figure out how to check the variable of the serialized object. I tried doing a ois.readObject and then reading that varaible but then I get an OptionalDataException. Also tried doing ois.defaultReadObject and then accessing by this.version but that only showed the current version, not the one I saved with.

Comment: Hey @akberc. Thank you so much for all of your help. I figured out a way to do it, although I don't know if it's the best way haha. What I did was made a `static final int NUM_OF_FIELDS` and a `int version` variable. I'll have to change both of those when I update the class but it works. In the readObject function I just compare `this.version` and `Foo.NUM_OF_FIELDS` and that seems to work for what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I was about to write some code to test it out and you saved me an hour or so.  Yes, you will have to update the code every time and test it out each time with an older version or versions and the current version.  A bit convoluted, but I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Deprecate the existing class, create a new class with the new structure and implement a constructor in the new class that can take the old object and convert it to the new version.

Assuming you created your old class against an interface, you can implement the same interface with the new class and the new objects will still be compatible with your old class.

Comment: I don't think that will work because I still have to read in an incompatible class which will throw an error.

Comment: Not sure I'm with you . . . you would read the object back in using the original class, there would be nothing incompatible, once the object had been converted, you would then serialise as the new object type.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you were meaning to still use the old class. But doing this would also mean that my new class would have to have a different name and my question is for the constant development of a class so that would get annoying. Sorry